# If function with formula to calculate difference between dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a difference between 2 dates using networkdays and additionally if both dates are equal, have to make the value as 0. But unable to get the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if(DATEVALUE(A1)=DATEVALUE(A2),0,NETWORKDAYS(A1+1,B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put your formula arguments in quotes?  That just changes them into strings, which is why your formula doesn't work.

I assume from your formula that you just don't want to count the first day. In which case it will work as you have it, if you merely remove the double quote marks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Ron Rosenfeld has pointed out that my testing led to wrong conclusions. Therefore I increased the volume of my tests. They continue to show that ...

1. Comparing the two dates and adding a day gives erratic results, and that
2. The naked NETWORKDAYS function as designed by Microsoft gives the most useful result.

In the table below the original function is in column C, your function (modified to work by @Ron Rosenfeld) in column D and two variations thereof in columns E and F. The lower part of the table shows results where both days are the same while the dates are 2 days apart in the upper part.

[image]

The tables show that the original formula counts both the start and the end days as well as all days between them, subtracting weekend days, except when start and end days are the same. In other words, the original function already treats the case of A1=B1 differently.

However, if an adjustment is to be made it should preferably be made to the result of the formula, not be modifying the date before they are processed. This is demonstrated in column F.

The formula in column E takes up your attempt to modify one of the dates (the end date could be modified too) and makes this conditional. The difference as compared to your formula is that you apply in fact two separate calculations, one where the result is always 0 (when dates are equal) and the other where the start date is advanced by one day unconditionally. If it suits your purposes that method can still be applied but the formula in column E shows how the date modification can be made conditional.

The need to apply conditions arises from the essential shortcoming of your formula in that it applies the wrong condition. Different treatment for when dates are equal is already incorporated in the basic function. Any further modification must take the involved weekdays into account, not (necessarily) only the interval between the dates.

Comment: `NETWORKDAYS` returns `1` if the two dates are the same, unless they are a weekend date. Try `=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2020,9,9),DATE(2020,9,9))`

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld. Yes, if the dates are the same they are likely to be on the same weekend. The tests I didn't do is if one day is in a weekend and the other isn't. Logically, the function should count either the first day or the last but not both. Therefore if both days are the same and a workday the result should be 1, otherwise 0. But if the days are 1 day apart the result may not be the same if the first day is a workday or the second one is.

Comment: Since the OP did not provide a comprehensive example of his expected results, we will have to await clarification as to whether he just wants to ignore the first day (which is what I infer from his formula attempt), or something else.  I was just pointing out that the first statement in your answer "`...returns 0 if both dates are the same.`" is incorrect, unless both dates are on the same weekend.  (or are the same and on a weekend).